# How to calculate break point values and ranges for point density heatmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have some questions about the point density analysis in ArcGIS. I am interested to know the concept and formula about how to come out with all the break point values and ranges of the different colour bands for point density heatmap. I hope any of you can provide me a rough idea about the concept and the formula to use. I want to know the rough Value/Range I can get using the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [How Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000011000000) page of the ArcGIS online help for the formula.
The symbology is based on the Gi_Bin field of the output feature class, see the [Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) (Spatial Statistics)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Hot_Spot_Analysis_Getis_Ord_Gi/005p00000010000000/) tool reference page.